# What is the point of buying new Jump Ships?

Tags: destiny

So the game starts you out with a basic Jump Ship to get around the system.  There's a vendor in the tower who sells other Jump Ships.

Do these other ships do anything special?  Or are they just hats? Expensive, cool looking, warp capable hats?

Comment: They are pure bling! At least as far as I have seen.

Comment: Man, I was really hopping for some space flight levels like in Halo: Reach.

Comment: Through story progression, you get a different jump ship as well.  Consider saving your glimmer for now, maybe you'll be happy with the other ship.

Comment: @CaulynDarr you never know, they might Star Wars: Galaxies it and add in space combat... but it seems highly doubtful sadly

Comment: @Eben if they did it they'd make it one-year-exclusive on the PS anyway.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They're just "hats".

But in addition to being cosmetic, they serve the social function of letting people know you're not a noob on the way to missions.

In both the Strike missions and the PvP missions, success is dependent on being able to work with your teammates. In Destiny there is no text communication and voice communication is not built in very well. This means that when embarking on the Strike missions in particular a player can only evaluate their randomly assigned teammates by looking at their gear. The ship and emblem they're using are both part of that gear and while they are not items that affect the actual gameplay, they are social indicators for the amount of time and experience someone has with the game.

Because of this some people may drop out of missions early if they believe that it is not in their interest to spend time playing with someone who has not yet learned the ins and outs of the Strike missions or PvP.

Comment: I was in the Beta on PS3, Xbox 360, and Xbox One. I've effectively played for several weeks. With the amount of glimmer you get, dropping about 3k for a new ship is cheap. I'm not saying it's fair to judge, I'm saying that I and other people do judge.

Comment: Do you play a lot of WoW Eben?

Comment: The game does have in game voice chat on xbox at least. And judging somebody on their gear is one thing (since it does show progression, etc.) but why judge based on a ship when you can judge on the gear? I am right in thinking that you can inspect anybody in your fireteam and not just people on your friends list aren't i? (I've yet to fireteam with somebody not on my friends list).

Comment: I understand where both parties are coming from, but one thing is "encouraging" discrimination through gear and another thing is merely describing discrimination through gear; I believe this answer does the latter. I don't play Destiny, but I do play Team Fortress 2, and I can safely say that even if you don't like it, or even if this answer is edited otherwise, this is still going to happen. So let's simply agree to disagree and move along.

Comment: After coming back to my answer I realized that I sounded much harsher than I meant to. So I edited my answer to reflect a general potential experience rather than my personal feelings.

Comment: @badp. I believe the original (unedited) answer _did_ encourage discrimination by saying `when I see someone in game with the noob ship I assume they're going to suck hard [...]. If they're not high enough level [...], I'll back out rather than waste time playing with them`. As it stands now, the answer is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yeah, my first answer was not very good... I probably shouldn't have posted it right after spending an hour in a Strike with two people who had no idea what they were doing and I had to solo the boss... So sorry to everyone for causing contention.

Comment: @Eben: Its good to see somebody on the internet stepping back and admitting they might be wrong for a change. :) I think the answer has been improved as well. :)

Comment: I figure if there is a "rarity" to the ship, cosmetic, yes, however legendary items may affect drop rate. And, on that, unless I am to figure that out, I'll have the original ship to the end. In regards to rank gauging... Grimore score shows that.

Answer (score 13):

I actually wrote a little about this today. I think jumpships are a value add for players that are basic visual customization, but they're a unique tool for Destiny to use to make a player actually like the loading screen experience of the game.

Summary: You get your jumpship early on in Destiny, and that jumpship sticks with you. You acquire a warp drive for it, and suddenly, you’re seeing your jumpship between every stage. Getting to the tower or another planet is a cinematic of your jumpship in travel. What it also is… is a loading screen. What it isn’t is a blanked out screen with a texture or spinning icon that says — LOADING. That’s not necessarily something brilliant, but then Bungie went and added player value to make you actually like the loading screen.

Starting with the original acquisition of your jumpship, you’re investing time and value in to an in-game object that you’ve acquired. Immediately from that point you have some affinity to seeing the jumpship as an achievement of your progress. Then, subsequently, Destiny adds further value by actually allowing the user to spend their in-game currency on more unique and visually detailed jumpships. Essentially — you can customize your loading screen. Of course, this is an in-game object so the motiviation to do so is actually there. No differently than gear… a player sees the opportunity to improve their jumpship and says… “Yes, I will make this ship fucking baller.”

My full post: http://offworlder.com/on-destinys-attention-to-the-loading-experience-aka-jumpships/

Comment: This is a good point. You can also see your ship being taken into the loading bay if you turn right just after landing at the Tower, which gives a sense of continuity between loading and running around.